# SSRS unexpectedly sorts by 1,10,11,12.. ,2, 20, 21

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

My code shows traffic per hour. I've done an ORDER BY hour in the SQL code.

In SQL, the results show in order of the hour as intended.

However, after making the report in SSRS, the hours show in the order 1,10,11,12... 2,20,21,22... 3,30,31,32...

In the table properties, I've specified the Sorting order. But it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaayy... I found the solution.

Apparently, because I was converting my hours to varchar, it was sorting the hours as characters. I converted the hours to int and that fixed the issue.

Thanks to [KenJ](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/users/202/kenj.html)